# Reading through PostgreSQL ranked results

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, ranking, postgresql-9.4

I'm new to PostgreSQL and I am working on a function to return the word locations for a searched word.

I want to first narrow down the text fields the search has to go though to make sure it is a relevant result from the database.

My table name is 'testing' then the text field column is called 'context' and the line number where it is located is called 'line_number'. Where the context text is associated with a specific line_number.

Right now my ranking code looks like this:

```
select line_number into lineLocation
from (
    SELECT
        testing.line_number,
        ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector('english', testing.context), 
        to_tsquery('Cats & Dogs & Kids')) AS score

    FROM Testing
) ranking
WHERE score >0 
ORDER BY score DESC;
Return QUERY select * from lineLocation;
```

When I try to print out lineLocation as a return query, it works in reporting the new ranked line numbers 22,19,21,20,17,13 each returned in their own column.

My problem now is that I want to search each of those lines (22 ... 13) for a key word like "dog" and return its position

Obtaining the text for that by using:

```
select context into sample from testing
  where testing.line_number = lineLocation;
```

If I try to just decrement the lineLocation in a loop like lineLocation -i 
It goes out of order, and will eventually search context that is not relevant.

Is there any type of 'read next line' function I could use? 
I am looking for a way to loop through the ranked result line numbers

**EDIT** I then go on to use a for loop where I want it to read through all of the rows of text in the column context from the ranked results

The problem I am having with this is that it only reads the first row of text in the column 'context' and I need it to look at all of the rows that are returned by the ranked search

Comment: Any reason why you don't want all that in one query?

Comment: What do you mean all in one query?

Comment: Well, why do you want to store data into `lineLocation` first.

Comment: I see what you're saying @JakubKania.  ' select context into sample ' so I don't need to use lineLocation. Yet it still does not read through all the lines of context, it only takes the first row of the column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up creating a ranking function of its own, and inserting the results of that text search into another table with a serial increment column.

filled the values of the new table (ranked_results) with this code:

```
INSERT INTO ranked_results(sentence) VALUES (columnRanking());
```

I also had to create a function to delete/reset the columns in the new table upon insertion of more lines.

```
TRUNCATE table ranked_results RESTART IDENTITY;
```